# Filter record in SQL Server based on 6 related fields

Tags: sql-server

Table 1 have 6 option set fields `A,B,C,` which hold values `0=false and 1=true` and `SendToA,SendToB,SendToC` which hold values `null=0, success=1, failure=2`.The checking is if any field `A,B,C`=`1(true)` then the fields `SendToA,SendToB,SendToC=1(success)`, extract the data. So what I did in sql query was:

> First Query

```
SELECT TableId
,A
,B
,C
,SendToA
,SendToB
,SendToC
FROM Table1
WHERE (A=1 AND SendToA =1) 
OR (B=1 AND SendToB=1) 
OR (C=1 AND SendToC=1)
```

> Second Query

```
SELECT TableId
,A
,B
,C
,SendToA
,SendToB
,SendToC
FROM Table1
WHERE (A=1 OR B=1 OR C=1) 
AND (SendToA=1 OR SendToB=1 OR SendToC=1)
```

This is example the executed result for second query.

```
TableId A B C SendToA SendToB SendToC
  ABC1  1 1 0  1         2       1
  ABC2  0 0 1  0         1       0
```

The problem there is certain record when any field `A,B,C=1(true)` but `SendToA,SendToB,SendToC is not = 1(success)`. If `A,B,C=0(false)` its doesn't matter any values in `SendToA,SendToB,SendToC`  These two query do not execute a correct result. to make its clear is I want to filter record based on if any values in `A,B,C = 1` then the values in `SendToA,SendToB,SendToC=1`, then extract the data. In record Its doesn't matter either `A or B or C=1` but at least either `A or B or C` must have 1 .Once `A or B or C=1` their belonging `SendToA,SendToB,SendToC` must also 1  or else ignore.

Comment: There queries are not the same, that's why they don't necessarily give the same result. What are you expecting?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what it is that you want? Is it so that you want to see rows were all the "sendings" have succeeded?

Comment: @user1429080 Hi I want to filter record based on any of A,B,C =1 And any of SendToA, SendToB and SendToC =1. But there are certain record in my table when A=1 and SentToA=1, however  B=1  and SendToB is not = 1. if B=o AND/OR C=0(dont bother to check either SendtoB AND/OR SendToC =1) AS long As A=1 and SendtoA=1. Just Check SendTo values =1 if their corresponding A Or B Or C =1. Sorry this is the best way i can explain.

Comment: I think best way should be to add well thinked sample data and your desired output

Comment: Hi Guys, to make its clear is I want to filter record based on if any values in `A,B,C = 1` then the values in `SendToA,SendToB,SendToC=1`, then  extract the data. In record Its doesn't matter either `A or B or C=1` and at least either A or B or C`  must have 1 .Once hold values your belonging `SendToA,SendToB,SendToC` must =1.

Comment: You should add into your question, as you wrote the output of your second query...

Comment: Sorry but this is just not clear. Is it? `At least one of A,B,C is 1 and ALL SendToA, SendToB, SendToC are 1` or `At least one of A,B,C is 1, and for each A, B, C that is one, the corresponding SendTo# must be 1`? If it's the latter, my answer shows how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for respond, this is the condition `If any or at least one of A,B,C is 1, and for each A, B, C that is one, the corresponding SendTo# must be 1 In order to meet the criteria else cannot.` For the first condition: `where (A=1 or B=1 or C=1) and (SendtoA=1 or SendToB=1 or SendtoC=1)`, is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want (see comment), but you can test this and see if it does the job:

```
-- prepare test data

declare @t table (
    TableId varchar(10),
    A int not null,
    B int not null,
    C int not null,
    SendToA int null,
    SendToB int null,
    SendToC int null
)

insert into @t values ('ABC1', 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1)
insert into @t values ('ABC2', 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
insert into @t values ('ABC3', 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
insert into @t values ('ABC4', 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

And then (replace `@t` with your real table name):

```
-- query

select *
from @t
where (A=0 or SendToA = 1)
    and (B=0 or SendToB = 1)
    and (C=0 or SendToC = 1)
    and (A=1 or B=1 or C=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful.